# Queriable Cache for MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, performance, caching, nosql

I have a requirement where I have to create a Cache-Layer for MySQL database. The Database is huge with around 100 tables and millions of rows in them. Almost all the tables have foreign key relations. 
For example:

Table : Rule

```
CREATE TABLE `rule` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_rule_code` (`code`)
)
```

Table : Params

```
CREATE TABLE `params` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rule_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `rule_id` (`rule_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `params_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`rule_id`) REFERENCES `rule` (`id`)
)
```

I'm able to store the rows of rule table with a key and similarly for 
params table separately. Now I want to get rows from both tables using some sort of where condition,similar to this :

```
Select * from rule r, params p where r.id = p.rule_id and r.id = (some_value);
```

1. Is there a way where I can cache the data and also performs joins on it?(Basically running the above query on cache)
2. What should I use for Caching for this? Aerospike, Redis, MongoDB etc.,
3. Can you give a basic idea of my wrapper class which performs the above operation (1) for this implementation

Comment: MySQL has a built-in cache, so maybe it would be more reasonable to start from trying to tweak it? 
https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/01/02/the-mysql-query-cache-how-it-works-and-workload-impacts-both-good-and-bad/ http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache-configuration.html

Comment: @MichałSznurawa The problem is that the data being fetched is large (around 30 Mb) and the tables being used get updated very frequently (around 3 updates/sec), so making the use of built-in cache not possible

Comment: can you write something more about how the data is used? How often are reads and if you need to get always the freshest copy?

Comment: @MichałSznurawa Always fresh copy is required. The reads are dynamic, which is on an average 1 per 3 secs right now. The data is fetched based on the parameters passed from the front end and is dynamic

Comment: So it seems like you will not take any advantage of standard cache per se. The data from cache will be most likely invalid when you will try to read it again after 3 seconds (according to that what you wrote). If you are experiencing issues with MySQL performance in described case, then I would say you should look for denormalization and keeping the data in structure exactly deterimned by your reads (to avoid joins). Look for the storage which offers cheap writes and reads for price e.g. of consistency or limited set of operations which you can execute on data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you demonstrated that there is a problem?  Based on what you said, you are about a factor of 30 from having any performance problems.  You can (probably) do 100, not just 3, updates per second, and simultaneously do hundreds (not 0.33) reads per second.

You do need for `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to be set to about 70% of *available* ram.

The query (with the `JOIN`) you presented should be no problem, given the indexes provided.

If you have a performance problem, you have not shown any evidence here.